# TypeError: SomeFunction is not a function (using Mongoose)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have this error: TypeError: User.getUserByUsername is not a function
   at Strategy._verify (.../routes/users.js:65:10)

```
var User = require('../models/user');

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.getUserByUsername(username, function(err,user){
    if(err) throw err;
    if (!user){
        return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknow User'});
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
        if(err) throw err;
        if(isMatch){
            return done(null,user);
        } else {
                return done(null, false, {message: "Invalid password"});
        }
    });
   });
  }));
```

The function is defined in models/user.js

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
var query = {username: username};
User.findOne(query, callback);
 }
```

Comment: can u share your user.js file

Answer (score 0):

Check what the `../models/user` module is exporting. From your description of the problem, it exporting something, but that something doesn't have a `getUserByUsername` function -- is that module perhaps exporting a prototype or class, which you should instantiate, eg:

```
var UserModel = require('../models/user');
var user = new UserModel();
...
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, you're using Mongoose (always good to mention in your questions). If not, disregard the following (but please update your question to signify which ORM you're using).

I think that you might be doing this in `models/user.js`:

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(...) {}
...
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', ...);
```

The latter assignment will replace `module.exports`, therefore making `getUserByUsername` unreachable.

Instead, it's probably better to make `getUserByUsername` a [static method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics), just like `comparePassword`:

```
userSchema.statics.getUserByUsername = function(...) {}
```

Comment: I have this statement: var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

Comment: @JanBeeck try adding `getUserByUsername` as a static, as suggested :)

Comment: @ robertklep Now I have this error: "ReferenceError: UserSchema is not defined at Strategy._verify (.../routes/users.js:66:5)" I have this definition on models/users.js UserSchema.statics.getUserByUsername = function()                                                        On another file named users.js I have the following: passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    UserSchema.statics.getUserByUsername(username, function(err,user)

Comment: @JanBeeck you should still use `User.getUserByUsername()` in your Passport code, making it a static is just another way to define it, similar to how `comparePassword` is defined.

Comment: @ robertklep comparePassword is defined as:   module.exports = comparePassword = function()

Comment: @JanBeeck in that case: make it a static Mongoose method as well :D That's why that feature exists.

Comment: @ robertklep Actually the error comes from a wrong definition of a function, I put module.exports = comparePassword = function() when the right way is module.exports.comparePassword = function() Thank you for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Try below , Change your User.js file as below:

```
exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
  var query = {username: username};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you assign to the `module.exports` later down the file? Exporting members should be declared after assigning to `module.exports` or `exports`

E.g.

```
    module.exports.getUserByUsername = function() {...};

    module.exports = User;
```

would be a common issue that resembles yours.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was because of a wrong declaration of one of the function of the process flow. 
All the functions have to be declared the same way in order to export correctly all the object.

```
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function()
```